# Connect Buildfire.js plugin to datastore using API key

Tags: javascript

Good day,
Can someone explain how I can connect my buildfire SDK to datastore, using the API key. what file do I go to, to do this?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Perhaps it would be help if you can be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to build a buildfire plugin using the SDK. I need help setting up the SDK.   I created a folder and placed the SDK files in that folder.  Everything seems to be working ok when I enter the localhost url for eg- localhost/Myplugin. I write some simple Javascript code to test the Datastore but its not working.  I added the API key I got from developer account on buildfire and added it to the script they specified, but I still can't connect to datastore.

Comment: Can you clarify what instructions you are following? I don't recall ever having to specify a datastore key. It's possible you are referencing older documentation.

Comment: How to test your Plugin locally

Comment: Download the SDK from here.
Create an account at http://developer.buildfire.com
Open scripts/appContext.js and enter your appId from the Developer Portal (top right of your screen) as a string in window.appContext.currentApp
If you choose to change your plugin folder name, make sure you change it as well in the scripts/appContext.js file.
Make sure when using the plugin tester, you run your local environment as static web server and not from your file system. Most IDE's should work (WebStorm, Eclipse, Brackets, Visual Studio, ...etc)

Comment: The above is the instruction.  I meant to say appID not API key

Comment: could you please tell me how u set up yours. I'm doing mine on localhost, Xampp

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you use the BuildFire CLI to help you develop plugins. It makes the whole process much easier.

You can get started by installing it from npm:

```
npm install buildfire-cli -g
```

Here's a detailed [blog posting](https://medium.com/@attilabuturla/creating-plugins-with-the-buildfire-cli-7592522ed277) covering the setup.

Comment: Will installing "BuildFire CLI" help me with the datastore

Comment: It will help you make plugins quicker. You shouldn't have to do anything with the datastore at all. I believe you are referencing out of date documentation.

Comment: Hey I have some issue installing the webpack template using "buildfire plugin init <pluginName> webpack" command.  I exchange the <pluginName> with flowershopPlugin but it does seem to create the plugin template in the plugins folder.  Could you please help me out here?

Comment: You should see the new plugin in the BuildFireSDK/Plugins folder.

Comment: If you do have an errors, it would help if you could post any error messages. Thanks.

Comment: Creating Plugin flowershop with tempalte webpack
Error: spawn git ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:217:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:394:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:174:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:228:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:575:3)

Comment: Error: Error: spawn git ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:217:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:394:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:174:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:228:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:575:3)
    at C:\Users\flitty007\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\buildfire-cli\node_modules\simple-git\promise.js:21:26
    at Git.<anonymous>

Comment: (C:\Users\flitty007\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\buildfire-cli\node_modules\simple-git\src\git.js:221:18)
    at Function.Git.fail (C:\Users\flitty007\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\buildfire-cli\node_modules\simple-git\src\git.js:1478:18)
    at fail (C:\Users\flitty007\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\buildfire-cli\node_modules\simple-git\src\git.js:1436:20)
    at C:\Users\flitty007\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\buildfire-cli\node_modules\simple-git\src\git.js:1445:16

Comment: What do you see if you run the following:
node -v

Comment: C:\Users\flitty007\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\buildfire-cli\BuildFireSDK>node -v
v10.0.0

Comment: Have you installed git? If not you can download it here: https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: No I haven't.  Is this the reason why I'm getting the error above?

Comment: Thank you for the help so far

Comment: Yes, you will need to install Git.

Comment: I did what u told to do and it solve the issue, but another problem popup. enter the

Comment: "buildfire run" command and it brought me to the pluginTester webpage but it doesn't show anything.  It's loading itself continuously.  What could be causing this and how can I fix it.  Thanks again a head of time you have been a big help

Comment: and could you point to some good resource to learn how to edit the webpack or code in the webpack template to make it my own.  I know the article you sent me to said you don't need to know much about webpack to use but I am new this, so I will need some information or tutorials to work with.

Comment: If you have questions about how to use a plugin based on the webpack template, I'm going to suggest that you post that as new question on StackOverflow.

Additionally, if you think my responses were helpful an upvote is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: will do, but you have not answer the question before that.  enter build run and launched the plugin tester. the control section of the plugin tester is loading continuously

Comment: What do you mean by "loading continuously"?

Comment: The content of the control section is not showing.  I only see the loading image, which is a blue dot inside a white circle.

Comment: I'm not following ... can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: how do I do that?  I try dragging the screenshot in the comment box but it doesn't work.